# Joins and anonymous types in SQLite

Tags: sqlite, windows-8, .net-4.5

I'm trying to do a few LINQ statements in SQLite but I'm getting a few problems.

First I'm trying to do a join. Here is my code:

```
var query = from client in db.Table<Client>()
    join address in db.Table<AddressDetail>()
    on client.AddressID equals address.AddressID
    select new
    {   
        ClientID = client.ClientID,
        AddressID = address.AddressID,
        Name = address.Name,
        LastSaveDate = client.LastSaveDate
    };
```

This fails and the error message I receive is : Joins are not supported.

Brilliant!!

So to get round this I split my code into 2 queries, so here is the updated code:

```
var query = db.Table<Client>();

foreach (var client in query)
{
    var subQuery = from address in db.Table<AddressDetail>()
                   where address.AddressID == client.AddressID
                   select new
                   {
                       ClientID = client.ClientID,
                       AddressID = address.AddressID,
                       Name = address.Name,
                       LastSaveDate = client.LastSaveDate
                   };

    foreach (var fullClient in subQuery)
    {
         //Do something here
    }
}
```

This all seems to work until I try to loop round the results of the subQuery. 
I receive the following error: No parameterless constructor defined for this object.

So do this mean that I can't use joins and anonymous types in SQLite?

Any ideas how I can get round this.

I'm using the SQLite, .Net 4.5 and am create a Windows 8 store app.

Answer (score 0):

Had you try this?
just add `ToList()` to table you want to join.

```
var query = from client in db.Table<Client>()
join address in db.Table<AddressDetail>().ToList()
on client.AddressID equals address.AddressID
select new
{   
    ClientID = client.ClientID,
    AddressID = address.AddressID,
    Name = address.Name,
    LastSaveDate = client.LastSaveDate
};
```

Comment: https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net/issues/193
(probably this isn't supported)